# iOS 7 - View Overlaps Status Bar Even After Setting Delta Y to 20

Tags: ios7

I have an app that was developed with iOS 6 sdk. Now I have updated the sdk and the target to iOS 7. After I made the switch and ran the app, I noticed that some of the UI elements were not positioned right in the simulator. I figured this was because of the translucent status bar. I changed the frame height of the view from 748 to 768 and set Delta Y to 20. i thought this will cause the view to start below the status bar. But it seems to overlap and the UI elements are not positioned as they were in iOS 6.

The settings I have tried:

- Frame Height 748, Delta Y 20
- Frame Height 748, Delta Y -20
- Frame Height 768, Delta Y 20
- Frame Height 768, Delta Y -20

In each case the status bar overlaps the view.

Simulator view (with old settings, frame height 748, no delta):
[image]

**[Update]** I tried setting Status bar style in info.plist to Opaque black style, and still the view overlaps the status bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I was editing the wrong file. I had recently switched from xib to storyboard and I had been editing the xib instead of the storyboard.

In the story board I moved my elements 20px down and that helped me have a similar view as in iOS6.

Answer (score 0):

if you still want the status bar but don't want it overlapping, just add this to your viewController

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```